# Need to select values of different type in DTO in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to select 2 differnt values having different datatype and use it in DTO

I have tried the follwing code this selects only the product name I also want to select Productid

```
var SubList = (from c in _context.Product    
               where (c.Id == Productid)
               select new productDto
               {
                    SubProduct = c.SubProduct,
               }).ToList().Distinct();

foreach (var subproductVal in SubList)
{
    String subproduct = subproductVal.SubProduct;
    var productList = (from c in _context.Product
                       orderby c.ProductName descending
                       where (c.SubProduct == subproduct)
                       select
                              c.ProductName
                      ).Distinct().ToArray();

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    subproductVal.ProductName = productList;
}
```

I need to select ProductId as well as product name

Comment: Will just using new { c.ProductName, c.ProductId } instead of c.ProductName work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
var SubList = (from c in _context.Product
                           where (c.Id == Productid)
                           select new productDto
                           {
                               SubProduct = c.SubProduct,

                           }).ToList().Distinct();

            foreach (var subproductVal in SubList)
            {
                String subproduct = subproductVal.SubProduct;

                var productList = (from c in _context.Product
                                   orderby c.ProductName descending
                                           where (c.SubProduct == subproduct)
                                   select new {
                                       c.ProductName,
                                       c.ProductId 
                                     ).Distinct().ToArray();
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                ...
             }
```

Then your `productList` is a array of anonymous type where every element of array is object of anonymous type.

Also you may add some class:

```
public class ProductInfo
{
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public string ProductName {get;set;}
}
```

Then your code looks like:

```
...

var productList = (from c in _context.Product
                                   orderby c.ProductName descending
                                           where (c.SubProduct == subproduct)
                                   select new ProductInfo {
                                       ProductName = c.ProductName,
                                       ProductId = c.ProductId 
                                     ).Distinct().ToArray();

...
```

Then each element of `productList` array is a object of class `ProductInfo`.

And finally, you code (as I see) is not optimal. You should rewrite it into one linq query (especially if you work with database).

Comment: Both productname and productid are of array type

Comment: You can write `var productNameArray = productList.Select(e=>e.ProductName).ToArray();`